# session not working on server in cakephp

Tags: session, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am working in cakephp. My all code working fine but when I upload the code on server then session functionality does not work.

There are no error on server.Just session does not write or read.
I am using go Daddy hosting.

my core file settings are:-

```
    Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'cake'
));

  // Session cookie now persists across all subdomains
  ini_set('session.cookie_domain', env('HTTP_BASE'));
```

and temp folder is writable and session id and other values in session are shown in temp folder file.but session still not working.

Comment: is the tmp folder writable?

Comment: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/cguyer/2009/10/18/mod-rewrite-on-godaddy-shared-hosting check this out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got my answer that there is a space problem after php closing tag in my one cotroller so just removed that space like

```
(?> ) to (?>)
```

Comment: sorry may I ask how does this becomes a problem?